# Kubernetes Service Resolution from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I have configured mysql cluster service and I am using the that service instead of hostname in jdbc url  in my application.properties. It is not resolving. But when I use the minikube URL, it is connecting correctly. Shouldn't DNS resolution happen for jdbc url as well in application.properties for a java project ?

Comment: yes, JDBC will do the DNS lookup.  your hostname not registered with kubedns service. create the service for your mysql cluster and use the service name in your jdbc url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @sfgroups mentioned, it is highly likely that the service has not been properly registered. Maybe you are using a different namespace or simply the service is not available. In order to check that:

- Run `kubectl get svc` and `kubectl get endpoints` to check if the service is registered and the mysql pods selected. It may sound silly but I advise you to check if the service name you are using is correct.
- If it is registered, try `kubectl get pods`, get the ID of your jdbc pod and launch `kubectl exec -ti <ID> nslookup <servicename>`. This will give you a hint if the dns resolution is working or not.
- If it is not resolving, then check in `minikube addons list` that `dns` is enabled. If it is disabled, enable it (you will need to wait a little bit) and try again.